# Keep events in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I have an instance of fullcalendar on my page. Every time, I insert an event (by a bootstrap modal), I also send the data with AJAX to a php file, which enters the content to a db. Then, everytime I call the page, the entries are taken from the database and appear in the calendar. I add the events with the following code:

```
var myCalendar = $('#calendar');
var myEvent = {
        title: '<?=$r['title'];?>',
        allDay: true,
        start: '<?=$r['startDate'];?>',
        end: '<?=$r['endDate'];?>'
};
myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent);
```

That's the code, where I directly add the event (after entering the information in a bootstrap modal), and also the code, where I add the event, after getting the information from the database.
This all works great, BUT: When I e.g. switch the month, the events don't appear any more, so when calling the page, all events from september are there, but when switching from september to october and back again, all events are not there any more. Why does this happen, and how can I change this behaviour?

Here is the full Code:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                    $('#add_date_modal').modal('show');
                    $('#add_date_startdate').val(date.format());
                    $('#add_date_startdate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',firstDay: 1});
                    $('#add_date_enddate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',firstDay: 1});
                },
                editable:true,
                selectable:true
            });
        });

        function addTitle(){
            var title = $('#add_date_title').val();
            var startdate = $('#add_date_startdate').val();
            var enddate = $('#add_date_enddate').val();
            var end_split = enddate.split('-');
            end_split[2]= parseInt(end_split[2])+parseInt("1");
            enddate = end_split[0] + "-" + end_split[1] + "-" + end_split[2];
            $('#add_date_title').val('');
            $('#add_date_startdate').val('');
            $('#add_date_enddate').val('');
            $('#add_date_modal').modal('hide');

            var myCalendar = $('#calendar');
            var myEvent = {
                title:title,
                allDay: true,
                start: startdate,
                end: enddate
            };
            myCalendar.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', myEvent );

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process_calendar_data.php",
                data: {
                    title: title,
                    start: startdate,
                    end: enddate
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <?php
    $dbh = new PDO(); //Database information
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM calendarData WHERE UID=?");
    $sql->execute(array($_SESSION['user']));
    while($r=$sql->fetch()){
        ?>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var myCalendar = $('#calendar');
                var myEvent = {
                    title: '<?=$r['title'];?>',
                    allDay: true,
                    start: '<?=$r['startDate'];?>',
                    end: '<?=$r['endDate'];?>'
                };
                myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent);
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }

    ?>
```

process_calendar_data.php:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $startdate = $_POST['start'];
    $enddate = $_POST['end'];
    $userID = $_SESSION['user'];
    $dbh = new PDO(...);
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO calendarData VALUES (?,NULL,?,?,?)");
    $sql->execute(array($userID,$title,$startdate,$enddate));
}
```

Comment: how are you saving these events to the database?

Comment: @CodeGodie I'm sending the data with AJAX to a php script, which just enters the data in the database....

Comment: what you should do is first run your ajax to save the events then use the `refetchEvents` to get all your events again

Comment: the problems is, that the events are only shown, until I switch the month, then they are away...

Comment: even when you run `mycalendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie Yes, and everything seems to work, so entering the events in the database and then relaoding them works... Is there maybe a callback or something like that, where I could say, that (`onChangeMonth() { ...refetchEvents....}`)?

Comment: You shouldn't need that. Can you show all your code so I can inspect

Comment: @CodeGodie added my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89458/discussion-between-codegodie-and-user3375021).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable mycalendar does not hold the right object, thats why refetchEvents does not work. You need to set it when you initialize it like so

```
var mycalendar = $('#calendar').fullcalendar ();
```

Then you can reference it properly

Also, you do not have an `events` option to render your events. The best way to do this, is to have a PHP script fetch all your events then turn them into JSON. Once you do that you set the results to the events option. See this: 
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/
this way when you call fetchEvents, they will fetch all saved events again
or in your case, when you click Next month, it will refetch automatically

Comment: but how can I access the variable then in all functions etc.?

Comment: I have a question. How are you loading your database events? you need to use the `events:` option as one of the API features but i do not see that in your code

Comment: it's in the code how I do it.. I just add a event (by calling render event) for every line I get back from the database, how else should I do it?